# How do I know which version of EOS the mainnet is running?

Tags: block-producer, mainnet

How do I know which version of EOS the mainnet is running?

For example, today is the mainnet running 1.0.3 or 1.0.4?

Is it possible that different Block Producers can be running different versions of EOS? Do they coordinate on updates?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the EOSIO version by making API call to [/v1/chain/get_info](https://eosio.github.io/eos/group__eosiorpc.html#v1chaingetinfo) endpoint and see the **server_version** property there, which is the first letters of the git commit id from the official repository https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/commits/master

For example, you can use http://dev.cryptolions.io/mainnet/ (or actually any BP API server from "Address" column) and go to [API](http://dev.cryptolions.io/mainnet/#api) and enter:

API Request: **/v1/chain/get_block**

You will see something like:

```
{
  "server_version": "c9b7a247",
  "chain_id": "aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906",
  "head_block_num": 1034339,
  "last_irreversible_block_num": 1034011,
  "last_irreversible_block_id": "000fc71b63fe1549e51aa84fd7619ccdbfff1eb3aca1109aed9fbd4c129bff70",
  "head_block_id": "000fc863ea9c26dfc4e3f34bb0059bcc61b107f98a472237606d5ac72f1ded8f",
  "head_block_time": "2018-06-16T15:23:49.500",
  "head_block_producer": "eosyskoreabp",
  "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 200000000,
  "virtual_block_net_limit": 1048576000,
  "block_cpu_limit": 199900,
  "block_net_limit": 1048576
}
```

where **server_version** exactly matches the https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/c9b7a2472dc3c138e64d07ec388e64340577bb34 commit and if you check https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases page it matches **v1.0.5** release.

You can query any blockproducer's api the same way, for example: https://mainnet.eoscanada.com/v1/chain/get_info

The official documentation is here: https://eosio.github.io/eos/group__eosiorpc.html#v1chaingetinfo

As I understand different block producers can run different versions, but they do great job to orchestrate and upgrade at the same time and run the same version - please someone correct me if I am wrong for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to EOS Go for the following information
For the status of the mainnet please follow along here: https://t.me/eosmainnet